# Utterance initial [ɾ]

Tags: pronunciation, phonology, phonetics

According to [The sounds of Japanese (Vance 2008)](http://www.cambridge.org/gb/knowledge/isbn/item1157656/?site_locale=en_GB):

> When /ɾ/ is the first phoneme in an utterance, the tip of the tongue is already resting lightly on the alveolar ridge, and /ɾ/ is produced by rapidly releasing this contact. Strictly speaking this utterance-initial allophone isn't a tap.

1. Can anyone elaborate on this utterance initial [ɾ] and its allophonic derivation, perhaps giving a reference for further reading? If it isn't a tap, then what is it? It sounds like it might be a voiced plosive, but it doesn't feel similar to either alveolar plosives [t, d]. It certainly sounds like there is an r-quality to it, but I wouldn't know how a plosive might acquire an r-quality.
2. Are you actually realizing, and furthermore aware of, an allophonic variant of [ɾ] (specifically the apparent utterance-initial allophone)?

Comment: You should provide an example (a minimal pair).

Comment: @sawa I know, but this is all the information I have! lolz. But this phone does not have a phonemic status, so a minimal pair in phonemes just doesn't exist. For a minimal pair in allophony, I think literally any other non-utterance-initial [ɾ] will serve as a phonetic contrast. Example: らちのらちです。the first [ɾ] must be the non-tap allophone where the second is a tap. This is really the best I can do.

Comment: I know this is answered, but is there a way you can clarify for future readers what you mean in layman's terms. For example "alveolar plosives" are not well known terms. Do you mean when is the R slightly rolled like a Scottish R and when is it more like an American L? I'm not a linguist and got lost pretty quick here... haha

Comment: @BillyNair okay I'll write an explanation, but it will take a bit of time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alveolar_lateral_flap) seems to say it is alveolar lateral flap, as opposed to the otherwise alveolar (central) flap. If you are serious, maybe you might want to try [the article](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=1799940) cited there. Trying this with myself, I seem to get the difference. I seem to be able to freely alternate an initial alveolar lateral flap with a centered one, but not a non-initial alveolar flap with a lateral one.

Comment: Stingy curmudgeons won't give it to me through my uni. And its a scant 3 pages. For $30US. For an international authority on phonetic transcription, their guidance is a little overpriced. Anyways, ty for helpful answer. I guess the features are [∓lateral] or [∓central] then.

Comment: @taylor Maybe it is ATR.

Comment: @taylor: You can buy [the *entire book*](http://www.amazon.com/Handbook-International-Phonetic-Association-Alphabet/dp/0521637511) for around 30 USD. The article itself is available [here](http://archive.org/details/rosettaproject_jpn_phon-2).

Answer (score 4):

According to ["Handbook of the International Phonetic Association: Japanese" by Hideo Okada](http://archive.org/details/rosettaproject_jpn_phon-2), /ɽ/ is pronounced

> postalveolar in place rather than retroflex[...]. Initially and after /ɴ/, it is typically an affricate with short friction, [image: [ɖɻ̝̆]].

In a more Unicode-friendly notation, this could be transcribed as [ɖɻ̝̆] (where again, these aren't really retroflex but only somewhat retracted from the alveolar position). The retraction would impart the *r*-coloring you perceive.

Coincidentally, this sound is almost identical to the American English  (**J**ohn), except with the fricative portion extra-short, for those speakers that don't palatalize it.

The Handbook continues:

> A postalveolar [l̠] is not unusual in all positions.

In summary, it sounds like [ɖɻ̝̆] and [l̠] are in free variation, with the former more common.